# [0].click or just .click?

Tags: javascript, click

I would like to know why some people use

```
element.click();
```

and others use

```
element[0].click();
```

What's the difference?

Thanks

Comment: [0].click() would be used if the variable element contains an array of elements and they are grabbing the first index

Comment: What is `element`? Completely depends. The `[]` operator is a member access operator. So the use in your question is getting the `0` member of the `element` object. So the first code calls `.click()` on the object itself, and the second calls `.click()` on the value of the `[0]` member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming element is a jQuery object, `element.click()` triggers a click event on a set of HTML elements that the `element` consists of. It's the same as calling `element.trigger("click")`

`element[0].click()` is invoking the click method on a DOM node (not jQuery object) that is the first in the set that `element` consists of.

See http://api.jquery.com/click/ (first case)

and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click (second case)

for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

They are very different, so they would be used in different contexts.

One calls click on the first element of an array, the other calls click directly on whatever `element` is